# Open bench logic sniffer Not working

Tags: logic-analyzer, sht15

I am using my openbench logic analyser for the first time in a real project. I am not getting valid captures though.

I have the latest client off dangerous prototypes website they recommend for mac. It can see the device & i can get the firmware version in the client.

I hook line 0 & 1 up to the data & sclk lines of my SHT15 temp sensor. Using a test sketch running on my Arduino I get the temp sent back to my serial monitor on the mac.

I capture the data on sniffer and all I get is channel-0 HIGH & channel-1 low for the whole capture this is using triggers to start the capture. The sketch is getting sensor data every 500ms. I have tried changing the sample rate no help. Also connecting the GND off the logic sniffer to GND on my Arduino changes nothing.

I can see the data signal on my oscilloscope with no problems though. The serial monitor is printing the correct temp as well

Can anyone point me in the correct direction please. I want to use the datasheet to come up with my own code to get the information off the SHT15 using logic sniffer to debug as I go

Thanks,

Comment: You musd always have a GND connection for proper operation. It's not optional, even if it doesn't seem to be solving the issue you see. Make sure it's properly connected to ground. Are you triggering the logic sniffer properly? It might be triggering immediately, in between the 500ms and so you don't see the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this link http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=23

Comment: Is that a link to a post or just the forum?

Comment: @AshleyHughes just the forum... specifically about the Open Bench Logic Sniffer